# Pythonic way to split a list into first and rest in Python 2.x?

Tags: python, list, split, python-2.x

I think in Python 3 I'll be able to do:

```
first, *rest = l
```

which is exactly what I want, but I'm using 2.6. For now I'm doing:

```
first = l[0]
rest = l[1:]
```

This is fine, but I was just wondering if there's something more elegant.

Comment: I think the above is fine. You could always do `first, rest = l[0], l[1:]`.

Comment: Indeed, you can't improve on the above -- http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532473/python-head-and-tail-in-one-line

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
first, rest = l[0], l[1:]
```

Basically the same, except that it's a oneliner. Tuple assigment rocks.

This is a bit longer and less obvious, but generalized for all iterables (instead of being restricted to sliceables):

```
i = iter(l)
first = next(i) # i.next() in older versions
rest = list(i)
```

Comment: Better is:  `first, last = l[:1], l[1:]`  in case `l` is empty (and it's prettier ;).

Comment: Should mention these are not semantically the same: `l[:1]` is a list,  `l[0] ` is an element of the list.

Answer (score 22):

You can do

```
first = l.pop(0)
```

and then `l` will be the rest. It modifies your original list, though, so maybe it’s not what you want.

Comment: This won't work for empty lists:
```x = []; x.pop(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Comment: @avyfain: neither would work the Python3 example of the OP. `first, *rest = []` raise a ValueError.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another one, working with python 2.7. Just use an intermediate function. Logical as the new behavior mimics what happened for functions parameters passing.

```
li = [1, 2, 3]
first, rest = (lambda x, *y: (x, y))(*li)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `l` is `string` typeI would suggest:

```
first, remainder = l.split(None, maxsplit=1)
```

Comment: `list` does not have a `.split()` method.

Comment: ooops ! my mistake, though it was for a string

Comment: Still +1 for while it is wrong in this case, it was a good thing, because I wanted to split string and assign head + rest of result to different variables.

Comment: Note this throws an error if the split only returns a list of 1 item