# Python List Multiple Assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How to do Python list multiple assignment in one line.

```
>>>a,b,c = [1,2,3]
>>> a
1
>>>b
2
>>>c
3
```

but what should I do to assign rest of the sub array to `c`

```
>>> a,b,c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] ##this gives an error but how to ..?
>>> a
1
>>>b
2
>>>c
[3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to split a list into first and rest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513947/pythonic-way-to-split-a-list-into-first-and-rest)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/): by adding `*` in front of `c`, c will catch all (rest) items.

```
>>> a, b, *c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```